# Parsing String java get index

Tags: java, string

I have a number of variable strings, of this type

```
  String 1 = s3345 section sector ground
  String 2=  s35 section sector ground
  String 3=  s99983 section sector ground
```

I have to take only the value of s, but this value is not fixed but variable.
how can I find the final index of s?

Comment: does this even compile?

Comment: Which s? The first one or any s?

Comment: You can split your string with `" "` and the use first part of that splited text if your number come in the starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the number always comes in starting

```
 String s = "s3345 section sector ground";
 System.out.println((s.split(" "))[0]); //check has to be applied for empty string.
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get the numeric value of `s3345` etc. and that part can be anywhere in the string, try to replace that value using a regular expression:

```
String input = "s3345 section sector ground";
String number = input.replace(".*\\bs(\\d+)\\b.*", "$1"); //number would be "3345"
```

If your input string is somewhat fixed, i.e. it's always `s<value> section sector <name>` you could add that to the regex to make it stricter.

Comment: that regex would fit any character that comes before the s like as3345, so I would make the regex match whitespace before and after like this ".*\\s*s(\\d+)\\s*.*"

Comment: @sharonbn if there is whitespace before that string then yes. A better solution would be the word boundary `\b` - I'll add that.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want just the number from each variable as a string.

```
    String one   = "s3345 section sector ground";
    String two   = "s35 section sector ground";
    String three = "s99983 section sector ground";

    // better off importing Scanner normally like this:
    // import java.util.*;
    // the star means to import every class including Scanner
    java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(one);
    String num = in.next();
    num = num.substring(1,num.length());

    System.out.println(num);
```

newbie tips:

- Be careful of naming variables. They should begin with a letter or underscore. Not a number.
- make sure each String literal(value) is within double quotes.
- make sure you end each statement with a semicolon --> ;